# Is there a way to divide a large mathematical equation into individual terms?

Tags: python, math, scipy

Hi I want to integrate a relatively long equation with Python and am looking for a way to divide the equation into multiple terms and simplify it.

This is the function ...

```
p = lambda r_st, b_st: 1j * np.exp(-1j*k*((np.sqrt(r**2 - 2*r*r_st * np.sqrt(1 - r_st**2/4*gross_r**2) * np.sin(alpha) * np.cos(b_st) + r_st**2))+(r_st**2/2*n*gross_r))) / (np.sqrt(r**2 - 2*r*r_st * np.sqrt(1 - r_st**2/4*gross_r**2) * np.sin(alpha) * np.cos(b_st) + r_st**2)) * r_st

p_int =  integrate.dblquad(p, np.pi, 2*np.pi, lambda r: 0.4, lambda r: r_m)
```

... and so similar I would like to divide them, because the term "l" occurs twice and allows a better over view.

```
l = lambda r_st, b_st: np.sqrt(r**2 - 2*r*r_st * np.sqrt(1 - r_st**2/4*gross_r**2) * np.sin(alpha) * np.cos(b_st) + r_st**2)

p = lambda r_st, b_st: 1j * np.exp(-1j*k* l +(r_st**2/2*n*gross_r)) / l * r_st

p_int =  integrate.dblquad(p, np.pi, 2*np.pi, lambda r: 0.4, lambda r: r_m)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way. Can someone help me find a similar solution.

Comment: Use the regular `def` function format.  It's easier to edit and break into lines.

Comment: Didn't you get an error message when you tried running your code? If you did, please read it carefully, and include it in your question post. You're not using the value of `l(r_st, b_st)` in `p` when you write `l`; instead your using "the function `l`", which is not what you want.

Comment: Try storing the result of `l(r_st, b_st)` in a variable: `def p(r_st, b_st): lrb = l(r_st, b_st); return 1j * np.exp(-1j*k* lrb +(r_st**2/2*n*gross_r)) / lrb * r_st`

Comment: I think you have different brackets in both examples - in second you have `... * k * l + ...` which means `(... * k * l ) + ...` but first runs `... * k * ( l + ... )` and this change result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, I forgot the parameters when calling the l function. Now it works.

```
l = lambda r_st, b_st: np.sqrt(r**2 - 2*r*r_st * np.sqrt(1 - r_st**2/4*gross_r**2) * np.sin(alpha) * np.cos(b_st) + r_st**2)

p = lambda r_st, b_st: 1j * np.exp(-1j*k* l(r_st, b_st) +(r_st**2/2*n*gross_r)) / l(r_st, bst) * r_st

p_int =  integrate.dblquad(p, np.pi, 2*np.pi, lambda r: 0.4, lambda r: r_m)
```